# Repeat some sequences in a Dataset in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have this dataloader inspired in [this example](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-datasets-and-dataloader-in-pytorch-for-custom-text-data-270eed7f7c00):

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class CustomTextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        data = self.X[idx]
        label = self.y[idx]
        return data, label

# define data and class labels
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

# define data set object
TD = CustomTextDataset(X, y)
# define dataloader
ddl = DataLoader(TD, batch_size=2)

for sample, target in ddl:
    print(sample)
```

In each batch, in this case of size 2, the print outputs 1, 2; then 3, 4; and then 5. But how can I get the first sample to be 1, 2; then 2, 3; then 3, 4; and last 4, 5? (That is, I repeat the last element).

Can it be generalized to use in the next batch the last `n` elements of the previous batch and as label not the position of `idx` but `idx+m`? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using a pytorch `DataLoader`. However you could create a custom function in the `CustomTextDataset` that retrieves a custom batch? Something like:

```
def get_custom_batch(self, k, n=1, batch_size=2):
    tmp_data = tuple([self[k - n + ii] for ii in range(batch_size)])
    X = torch.cat([x[0][None, ...] for x in tmp_data], dim=0)
    y = torch.cat([x[1][None, ...] for x in tmp_data], dim=0)
    return (X, y)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is `k` playing the role of what I called `idx`?

Comment: Yes that's right, apologies!